# web socket with Django channels

Tags: django, python-3.x, ssl, websocket, django-channels

I am writing a small prototype of e-vote where each person will vote, but the vote will be encrypted with Shamir's secret-sharing, so the result of the vote will be displayed only if all voters meet. i do not know if it's feasible but for that i would like to integrate django-channel to my existing project to create real-time communication between users and wait for all voters to log in and enter one of their passwords (to decrypt key numbers) in the database) and valid to display the results at temp reel (I never use Django-channel).

So my question is:

is it possible? and can I run WSS (websocket secure) in my localhost, if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne).

> Daphne is a HTTP, HTTP2 and WebSocket protocol server for ASGI and ASGI-HTTP, developed to power Django Channels.

That said, if it's just for a demo, you can probably get by with JavaScript polling your server.